# java: change hashmap values to another value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a map like this.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("sun",0);
map.put("Sunday",0);
map.put("sund",0);
map.put("Mon", 1);
map.put("Tues", 2);
map.put("Wed", 3);
```

I want to change the entries having the value 0 to new value 7.ie, something like this:

```
map.put("sun",7);
map.put("Sunday",7);
map.put("sund",7);
```

How can i do this ?? 
Thanks

Comment: Iterate, Check, Change. You can search how to iterate through maps if you're unsure

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    for(Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() == 0) {
            e.setValue(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code ,may help you:

```
if (hashMap1.containsKey(key))
{
   valuesCopy = hashMap1.get(key); // first, copy out the existing values
   valuesCopy.add(newValues++); // insert the newValues to the value Set
   hashMap1.put(key, valuesCopy); // insert the key-value pairs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by:

```
 for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: map.entrySet()){
        if(0 == (e.getValue())) {
            e.setValue(7);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     if(e.getValue() == 0) {
         e.setValue(7);
     }
}
```

It should Work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> keyValues = map.keySet();

for(String s : keyValues){
   int i = map.get(s);
   if(i == 0)
    {
      map.put(s,7);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
Courtesy : http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/HashMaps/

HashMap methods to alter what is in the HashMap

```
Object objectReplacedForKey = 
  hashMapName.put(objectKey, objectToAdd); 

hashMapName.putAll(mapToAdd); 
hashMapName.remove(keyObject);  
hashMapName.clear();
```